# Setting up Facets in Elasticsearch with Searchkick gem in Rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, searchkick

I want the users to be able to easily find a series so want to set up facets. I have followed the directions at [seachkick](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#facets) and everything is working fine, but when I setup Facets, I am getting the following as the return. I want it to be like in their documentation. Hope someone can help.

I get this in myapp.com/movies

```
{
  "name"=> {
    "_type"=> "terms",
    "missing"=> 0,
    "total"=> 1,
    "other"=> 0,
    "terms"=> [
      {
        "term"=> "Bloop",
        "count"=> 1
      }
    ]
  },
  "imdb"=> {
    "_type"=> "terms",
    "missing"=> 0,
    "total"=> 1,
    "other"=> 0,
    "terms"=> [
      {
        "term" => "http://www.bloop.com",
        "count" => 1
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

---

```
#app/views/movies/index.html.erb
<%= p @series.facets %>
```

---

```
#app/controllers/movies_controller.rb
def index
  query = params[:query].presence || "*"
  @movies = Movie.search(query, page: params[:page],
                                suggest: true,
                                per_page: 20,
                                facets: [:name, :imdb])
end
```

---

```
#db/schema.rb
create_table "movies", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.text     "description"
  t.string   "imdb"
  t.string   "year"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally got it working by doing the following. Not sure if it is the best method but it works! Hope it helps and if you have improvements or suggestions feel free to let me know.

```
# app/models/movie.rb
def self.facets_search(params)
  query = params[:query].presence || "*"
  conditions = {}
  conditions[:year] = params[:year] if params[:year].present?

  movies = Movie.search query, where: conditions, 
    facets: [:year], 
    smart_facets: true, page: params[:page], suggest: true, highlight: true,
    per_page: 10
  movies
end
```

.

```
# app/controllers/movies_controller.rb
def index
  @movies = Movie.facets_search(params)
end
```

.

```
# app/views/movies/index.html.erb
<% if @movies.facets["year"]["terms"].present? %>
    <div>
        <ul>
        <% @movies.facets["year"]["terms"].each do |filter| %>
          <li><%= link_to "#{filter["term"]} (#{filter["count"]})", "/movies?year=#{filter["term"]}" %></li>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: @crentist how do you maintain the `query` if the facet is selected?