# How to find certain range of values from the results of find_by method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch

I have an attribute rank in a table whose values range from 1-100. I would like to perform facet search on it by providing options to a range of rank values such as 1-5, 6-10 etc.

I currently have the following code in my view file

```
<%= link_to_unless_current Univ.find(facet['term']).rank, params.merge(id: facet['term']) %>
```

which seperately displays the values.

Is there a way that I could perform a range search on the attribute?

Please help

Comment: It's not recommended to do querying in the view, do it in the controller and pass it to the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check the following question which implements facet by using Searchkik

[Setting up Facets in Elasticsearch with Searchkick gem in Rails 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23354154/setting-up-facets-in-elasticsearch-with-searchkick-gem-in-rails-4-1)

Hope that gives you an idea to implement using tire

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Rnage within `where` values:

```
Model.where(value: 1..5)
```

If you for example need values to be in range 1-20 or 45-70, youc an wrap them in array:

```
Model.where(value: [1..20, 45..70])
```

Comment: That worked however instead of displaying as 1..5 and 6..10 it shows

         #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Univ:0x007fd52cae4328> (1)

Comment: <%= link_to_unless_current Univ.where(value: [1..5, 6..10]), params.merge(id: facet['term']) %> 

is my code in view